# How to make preloader execute on image load in javascript for wordpress site

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, dom, preloader

The first images of my slider are loading after page load. I want the page viewed with the first slides displayed. I have written a function that creates a div overlay that hides the page initially. I need a function (can be in Jquery) that will hide the div overlay when triggered by an event that will result in the hiding of the div overlay when the first images of my slider are displayed. Site in question: [applaudvideo.com](http://applaudvideo.com) password: goonies

Javascript (this is in the header.php of my WP site. It creates the div that hides the page.)

```
if (document.getElementById) {
document.write('<style type="text/css" media="screen">#overlay 
{display:block;height:100%;width:100%;background:#2E0854;position:fixed;z-index:99999}
</style>');
}
```

CSS: (in body)

```
<div id=overlay></div>
```

The above function works. I just need a function that will hide the div overlay by binding or listening to an event. The function would be triggered, hide the overlay div, and the slider's images would already be rendered/displayed.

The following are functions I think I can bind or listen or attach to to hide the div overlay:

> Copy and Paste the Below listed API Functions into your Functions for Event Listening.

```
revapi10.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e) {
//alert("slider loaded");
```

});

```
revapi10.bind("revolution.slide.onbeforeswap",function (e) {
//alert("before swap");
```

});

```
revapi10.bind("revolution.slide.onchange",function (e,data) {
//alert("slide changed to: "+data.slideIndex);
```

Comment: Wordpress uses javascript, html and css? The answer to my question will involve one, or all, of the aforementioned topics. The question's answer would be a way to hide a div (CSS) with a script (javascript,jquery,prototype,COBOL) on the load of an object(HTML).  As the images appeared to be the last items loading the above method seemed correct but that won't work for several reasons. Browser cache being one. The other being the page renders objects after the images loaded. Thanks for the link though I will try them too.

Comment: I would like anyone to explain how this is off-topic. Its a javascript question. When I moved it too wordpress.stackexchange the first poster said it was a javascript question: [link]http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110232/script-help-for-a-preloader-hide-page-until-all-elements-load

Comment: The first part of the function works.

'code'(if (document.getElementById) {
document.write('<style type="text/css" media="screen">#overlay 
{display:block;height:100%;width:100%;background:#2E0854;position:fixed;z-index:99999}
</style>');
}
)



An overlay div is created before any of the page is rendered. Hiding the div is where I need assitance. img.onload is not correct unless I use browser cache workarounds. I think the hiding function needs to be attached or binded to an event within the slider.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is not off topic on SO (although it is indeed npt 100% clear what the question is about)

Comment: AFAIK your code already contain the workaround for caching on IE.